# How send parameters with URL in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I send a parameter with this

```
apiUrl = SERVER_API_URL + '/api/import/estimatee/' + this.state.estimateId;
.post(apiUrl, formData, config)
```

but I need to send parameters like

```
apiUrl = SERVER_API_URL + '/api/import/estimatee/' + this.state.estimateId + this.state.purchaseOrder.purchaseOrderName + this.state.purchaseOrder.purchaseOrderCurr
```

How can I solve this Thanks for your feedback people?

Comment: Why have you put the other parameters in quotes?

Comment: Depends on API I suppose, but I'm guessing separate them by `&`

Comment: like this ? this.state.estimateId & this.state.purchaseOrder.purchaseOrderName & this.state.purchaseOrder.purchaseOrderCurr

Comment: kind of. like `this.state.estimateId + '&' + this.state.purchaseOrder.purchaseOrderName + '&' + this.state.purchaseOrder.purchaseOrderCurr`

Comment: i tired for two parameters and i get this error http://localhost:9000/api/import/estimatee/1&undefined 404 (Not Found)  1 is my first parameter it is ok but second &undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const { estimateId, purchaseOrderName } = this.state;
const apiUrl = `${SERVER_API_URL}/api/import/estimate/${estimateId}/${purchaseOrderName}`;
```

im solved this way thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Use `template literals` with query parameters `?` and `&` to include multiple parameters:

```
const { estimateId, purchaseOrderCurr, purchaseOrderName } = this.state;

const apiURL = `${SERVER_API_URL}/api/import/estimate/order?estimateId=${estimateId}&purchaseOrderName=${purchaseOrderName}&purchaseOrderCurr=${purchaseOrderCurr}`
```

`apiUrl` will now be:

```
http://serverapi/api/import/estimate/order?estimateId="1234"&purchaseOrderName="orderName"&purchaseOrderCurr="USD"
```

Then you can use `axios` to `post` to `apiUrl`:

```
axios.post(apiUrl, formData, config);
```

**OR**

just paste the parameters in axios's `options` -- **these parameters should be appended to `formData`, especially if they are relevant to what's being submitted in `formData`**:

```
const { estimateId, purchaseOrderCurr, purchaseOrderName } = this.state;

axios.post(`${SERVER_API_URL}/api/import/estimate`, { formData, estimateId, purchaseOrderCurr, purchaseOrderName }, config);

OR

const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('estimateId', estimateId);
fd.append('purchaseOrderCurr', purchaseOrderCurr);
fd.append('purchaseOrderName', purchaseOrderName);
...other formData options

axios.post(`${SERVER_API_URL}/api/import/estimate`, fd, config);
```

Comment: i get this error error: "Not Found"
message: "Not Found"
path: "/api/import/estimate/order"
status: 404   and in console msj is xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:9000/api/import/estimate/order?estimateId=1&supplierId=1&paymentModeId=1 404 (Not Found)

Comment: and when i use like this `const { estimateId, supplierId, purchaseOrder } = this.state;
   const apiUrl = `${SERVER_API_URL}/api/import/estimate/order?estimateId=${estimateId}&purchaseOrderName=${purchaseOrder}&purchaseOrderCurr=${supplierId}``  **i get this error** detail: "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "order""
message: "error.http.400"
path: "/api/import/estimate/order"
status: 400
title: "Bad Request"